# How can I fix Laravel 5.1 - 404 Not Found?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use Laravel 5.1 for the first time. I was able to install it and `https://sub.example.com/laravel/public/` is displaying what is should. However, views I create are giving me a 404 error Page not found.

Here is what I have done so far:

I created a controller in `laravel\app\Http\controllers\Authors.php`

Here is the code behind the `Authors.php` file

```
<?php

class Authors_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;

    public function get_index() {
        return View::make('authors.index')
            ->with('title', 'Authors and Books')
            ->with('authors', Author::order_by('name')->get());
    }
}
```

Then I created a view in `laravel\resources\views\Authors\index.blade.php`

Here is the code behind the `index.blade.php` file

```
@layout('layouts.default')


@section('content')
    Hello, this is a test
@endsection
```

Then I created a layout in `laravel\resources\views\layouts\default.blade.php`

Here is the code behind the `default.blade.php` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ $title }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    @if(Session::has('message'))
        <p style="color: green;">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
    @endif

    @yield('content')
    Hello - My first test
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally I created a route in `laravel\app\Http\routes.php`

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('authors', array('as'=>'authors', 'uses'=>'authors@index'));
```

But for some reason I keep getting 404 error Page not found.

I enabled the mod_rewrite on my Apache 2.4.9 by uncommenting out the line

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Then restarted Apache.

From what I can tell in the `php_info()` output the mod_rewrite is enabled

```
Loaded Modules 
core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_php5 mod_access_compat mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_dir mod_env mod_include mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_socache_shmcb mod_ssl
```

My current .htaccess file looks like this "which is the factory default"

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I have also tried to change it to the code below as per the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

However, I am still getting the 404 page when I go to

```
https://sub.example.com/laravel/public/authors
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I see the same behaviour of being able to visit the / route but all other pages return a 404 when I first setup Laravel sites.

In your apache config file httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf you need to enable the directives that can be placed in the .htaccess file.

Here is an example of my VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/laravel_authority-controller_app/public"
    ServerName authoritycontroller.www
    ErrorLog "logs/AuthorityController.www-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/AuthorityController.www-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:/www/laravel_authority-controller_app/public">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The key entry for your issue is `AllowOverride All`. This should be enough to get the website working but you can also include `options` and `Require all granted` if they are consistent across the entire website.

Comment: How do i do this in a windows server? or could this be my problem, i have the same issue, home url works but no other url works, even when route is defined.

Answer (score 9):

if you are on ubuntu you shoud do 3 thing.
 1. check if "/var/www/html/YourProject/public/ .htacess " is like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

2. Add this lines on  /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
 AllowOverride all
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Note: remember that is an system file so you should use this comamd

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

3. by last enable rewrite module.

   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

or

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Answer (score 3):

If your Laravel routes aren't working, and you're getting "Not Found" errors whenever you try and load a page, your .htaccess file is likely lacking permission to do its duty.

The key is the apache AllowOverride directive.

If you don't have AllowOverride set to All, your Laravel .htaccess file (`/public/.htaccess`) won't be able to enable mod_rewrite, and your routes won't work.

The first step is to open your apache httpd.conf file. In OS X, it is located at:

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Option 1) Modify your main  directive

This will change the AllowOverride value for all your websites. In your httpd.conf file, look for the main  directive:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    ...
    AllowOverride None
    ...
</Directory>
```

Simply change it to this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    ...
    AllowOverride All
    ...
</Directory>
```

Option 2) Add a  directive to your site's  directive.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/epigroove/public"
    ...
    <Directory "/var/www/html/epigroove/public">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Save the changes to your `httpd.conf` file, restart or reload apache, and your routes should be up-and-running.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Apache HTTPD 2.2.15 on Linux (CentOS 6.7 in my case), then the directory directive will look like this

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI  
    AllowOverride All  
    allow from all  
</Directory>
```

You probably don't need the Options line though, unless you're using those options.

Thank you to the 2.4 answer. It helped me solve this issue for me on 2.2 and I have another server running 2.4 I can apply it to too.

Answer (score 1):

if its on a live server, try this, it worked for me tho.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

also, the `URL` is **case sensitive** to the folder name

folder name: `camelCase`
then the url must be `localhost/camelCase/route-1`

hope this help someone xD, little bit silly