# laravel 5 https always 404 for any route

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, laravel-5

I have laravel 5 running ubuntu on aws with apache2. The site and route works with no http.

When hit e.g. https://example.com, only the home page works. The other pages returns 404. e.g. https://example.com/home returns 404

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

the 000-default.conf
[image]

the ssl.conf
[image]

The servername don't have be there for aws to work.

Comment: I face the same problem, do you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

based on this: [How can I fix Laravel 5.1 - 404 Not Found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575770/how-can-i-fix-laravel-5-1-404-not-found)

the ssl conf need to "mirror" 000-default.conf. i.e.

```
<Directory>
......
</Directory>
```

This part needs to copy to the apache ssl conf from 000-default.conf