# New routes in Laravel are not working

Tags: laravel-5

I just tried to add a new route in Laravel but it seems it's not working, just getting 404 errors.
It only detects the index '/' route.
This code is in the routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'SiteController@mainView')->name('home');
Route::get('secondroute','SiteController@secondRoute')->name('secondRoute');
```

The Controller is also working, because it doesnt matter if the index Route (/) is the mainView or SecondRoute so it has to be something with the routing itself?

Thanks

Edit: Mod Rewrite is on

Edit2: I'm using a Ubuntu on a Virtual Machine with Apache 2.4.25

Edit3:

```
 public function secondRoute(){
    return view('myself', ['title' => 'Myself']);
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you put it first?

Comment: got the same 404 error, it only takes the '/' route

Answer (score 1):

You missed '/' in second route

change

```
Route::get('secondroute','SiteController@secondRoute')->name('secondRoute');
```

to

```
Route::get('/secondroute','SiteController@secondRoute')->name('secondRoute');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, allready tried it, it doesn't make difference

Comment: it's an 404 error.
But I just saw, when I'm using the  {{route('')}} function in blade and use for the parameters a route that is not defined like 'blubb' I'm getting this: ErrorException
Route [blubb] not defined.
Seems it's a server problem?

Comment: i dont think its a server problem .its a problem of not found i.e. 404

Comment: can you show secoundRoute method of site controller

Comment: i think you have to change in your .htaccess file. try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575770/how-can-i-fix-laravel-5-1-404-not-found